# CMake detect if no C++ compiler present

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I have a project that first uses a C++ program to process some template files (setup as a subdirectory) and then needs to cross-compile to run on vxworks. The cross compile part will be done via a custom command and .bat file but the first part will vary depending on the available options.

If the computer has an appropriate compiler it should compile the template processor program as necessary before running it. Some computers, though, won't have a regular c++ compiler. In this case I want to assume that the template processor program is installed to a specific location and continue using that prebuilt version.

How would I go about tackling this with CMake?

Comment: Looks like you need [compiler feature check](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).

Comment: The feature check only seems valid after it has found a compiler. In my case, no compiler would be found so it will produce an error right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `try_run` a try. It compiles and executes C++ source code. If execution fails. it is indicated in the failed run variable you pass as the first argument.
The advantage of using this is, that you don't have to take care of the right compiler call or any flags.

Documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/try_run.html
Especially the [section about cross compilation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/try_run.html#behavior-when-cross-compiling)